# Wordpress Power Builder not working

Tags: wordpress

I am new to Wordpress. I've bought a template and it uses the Power Builder plugin. I've worked with it on my other websites and it worked perfectly fine. However, I just started to create a new website today and I am hosting it on my Mac. After I installed the template along with Power Builder, the interface changed to a bunch of code instead of the "builder" interface.

This is what I get when I host it on my Mac.
[image]

This is the one I host on Google Cloud.
[image]

How do I get the "builder" blocky interface?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Can you check if the php.ini configuration is the same in both the setups. short_open_tag can cause this issue.

Comment: I have no idea where to check this...

Comment: it should be in your php installation folder.